How to use typescript-generator to generate enum with field
I am trying to use typescript-generator to generate a Typescript enum from a Java enum.
My example Java enum:
public enum DefinedFields {
    DEFINITION("definition"),
    HAS_DIRECT_CHILDREN("hasDirectChildren");

    private final String text;


    DefinedFields(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}


Here is the relevant bit from my Maven pom:
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>cz.habarta.typescript-generator</groupId>
                <artifactId>typescript-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1263</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jsonLibrary>gson</jsonLibrary>
                    <mapEnum>asEnum</mapEnum>
                    <classes>
                        <class>DefinedFields</class>
                    </classes>
                    <outputKind>module</outputKind>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

When I run Maven, the following is generated in DefinedFields.d.ts:
export const enum DefinedFields {
    DEFINITION = "DEFINITION",
    HAS_DIRECT_CHILDREN = "HAS_DIRECT_CHILDREN",
}


However, what I need to be generated is:
export const enum DefinedFields {
    DEFINITION = "definition",
    HAS_DIRECT_CHILDREN = "hasDirectChildren"
}

That is the enum values need to correspond with the Java text field.
Some questions you may have

Why not just recreate the enum manually in Typescript? We have a lot of enum values and it will really help reduce errors if we can define it once.

The values of the text field are non-negotiable. I.e., we cannot change it to correspond with the generated Typescript values.


